# Symfony DQL: fetching null in value of month while grouping the data according to month and year

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

neither the month is displayed here nor the data is being grouped according to the month, I am just fetching total sum or all fields and empty month value!, this is the query:

```
$em = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager();
        $conn = $em->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.timestamp)) as mon, SUM(s.amt) as total FROM sales s GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.timestamp)) ORDER BY mon";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $all_rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
            echo "Month: {$row["mon"]}, Total: {$row["total"]} \n";
        }
```

TABLE VALUES:

1. 2016-05-26 00:00:00 - 150
2. 2016-05-24 00:00:00 - 300
3. 2016-05-26 00:00:00 - 250
4. 2016-04-24 00:00:00 - 380

so the output should be:
month: 4 amt: 380
month: 5 amt: 700

but getting:

> month: , amt: 1080

any solutions?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() may not be necessary here since your Date is stored as a DateTime TYPE. I bet this is what you want to do:

```
<?php

    $this->get("doctrine")->getManager();
    $conn       = $em->getConnection();
    $sql        = "SELECT MONTH(s.timestamp) as mon, SUM(s.amt) as total FROM sales s GROUP BY MONTH(s.timestamp) ORDER BY MONTH(s.timestamp)";
    $stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $all_rows   = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
        echo "Month: {$row["mon"]}, Total: {$row["total"]} \n";
    }
```

Below is a shorter variant of the Query using your preferred syntax (Aliases)...

```
<?php
    $this->get("doctrine")->getManager();
    $conn       = $em->getConnection();
    $sql        = "SELECT MONTH(s.timestamp) as mon, SUM(s.amt) as total FROM sales s GROUP BY mon ORDER BY mon";
    $stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $all_rows   = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
        echo "Month: {$row["mon"]}, Total: {$row["total"]} \n";
    }
```

Here is a screen-shot of the dump, tried from Symfony3:

[image]

Comment: Please do not deface your answer.  If you want to remove it, delete it.